# Problema en expresión regular de una funcion lineal en java

Tags: java, regex

Tengo este problema y es que esta expresión no me evalúa las ecuaciones de forma correcta. Ejemplos de esto serían:

1. `3x1+5x2+6x3>=9`
2. `x1>8`
3. `x3<=8`

Traté de hacerlo pero las expresiones regulares no se me dan, así lo trate de hacer.

```
public static boolean PatronEcuacion(String str) {
    return (str.matches("^[\\d]|[x].*[+-]?[<=>=]?[\\d]$"));
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás tratando de obtener la expresión lineal de una función lineal o una desigualdad lineal?

Comment: estoy tratando de obtener la expresión lineal @dwarandae

Comment: @Efrainrodc un regex no "evalúa" una ecuación. Honestamente, luego de leerlo varias veces, y viendo tu expresión, no me queda claro qué estás intentando hacer. Te recomiendo leer los requerimientos para preguntas de regex que están en http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info. Mientras tanto, estoy votando para poner en pausa la pregunta, pero espero que puedas [edit] la pregunta para que se entienda el objetivo y poder retirar los votos o reabrirla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es una expresión regular como ésta:

```
^([+-]?\d*x\d)+[<>]?=?\d+$
```

que comprobando en [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QBrnuR/1) verifica todas los casos que pones:

- 3x1+5x2+6x3>=9
- x1>8
- x3<=8

Con esa expresión lo que se comprueba es lo siguiente:

1. Debe haber al menos uno de lo siguiente:

   - Un signo opcional de `+` o `-`
   - Seguido opcionalmente de un número (de los dígitos que sean)
   - Seguido de una `x`
   - Seguido de un dígito
2. Que irá seguido opcionalmente por `<` o `>`
3. Y por un `=` opcional también
4. Terminando con un número (de al menos un dígito)

Comment: muchas gracias @AlvaroMontoro